# What is the most effiecient way to get Factorial Sum?

Tags: python

The code is to find the factorial of each individual value in an array and then find the sum of them together .An example would be [1,2,3,4], which will then be 1!+2!++3!+4!=33.A single integer equal to the desired sum, reduced modulo . The issue is that when it comes on to large numbers(just my assumption) it results in "Terminated due to timeout" status

At first I used a for loop to go through each value in the array. Thinking that it may be a search issue I used for in range to ensure it has a set range. Sadly that still hasn't solved the problem. I now assume that it has to be a problem with factorial since multiplication is

```
def factModSum(arr):
    sum=0
    for i in range (0,len(arr)):
        sum=sum+factorial(arr[i])

    return sum%(10**9)
```

Example 1:

```
Input: 1 2 3 4
output: 33
Expected output: 33
```

Example 2:

```
Input:2 3 5 7
Output:5168
Expected output: 33
```

Example 3:

```
Input:12 13 14
Output:884313600
Expected output: 33
```

At the core of it at the function works. But Im getting timeout error for some of my Test case , therefore assuming that the code is not able to process large numbers in a given time

Comment: Is there a reason you are doing `%` with `10 ** 9`?

Comment: `def factorial(n)` code is missing. I assume that it is a recursive function and that probably causes the timeout, because it runs too long?

Comment: @StefanBecker I assume it's through `from math import factorial`.

Comment: @StefanBecker Integer overflows won't happen in Python. Plus, you can skip computation for factorials greater than 40. See my answer.

Comment: Just tried `print(factModSum((10000, 20000, 30000)))`. Seems to work. Can you give an example input where you run into the error?

Comment: @StefanBecker. The code does work but the problem I’m having is that it tends to timeout. Which means the time it takes may be too long

Comment: @Sage Python code doesn't "timeout". This must be an error message from the environment where you run your python script on. Calculating large factorials *does take time* so if your environment limits your CPU cycles, then you have a problem that can't really be fixed by changing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are modding by `10 ** 9` you can try this:

```
def factModSum(arr):
    return sum(factorial(i) for i in arr if i < 40) % 10**9
```

This is because `n!` with `n >= 40` is congruent to `0 mod 10**9`.

Comment: Tried this method and it was a success thanks again